# Trying to center a horizontal LinearLayout layout

Tags: android

I'm dynamically creating horizontal  LinearLayout with 5 views added to each one.  It is then added to a vertical LinearLayout that is inside a scroll view.

I set the gravity   by layout.setGravity( Gravity.CENTER );, but it is not centred but left algined.

THe code that creates the  horizontal  LinearLayouts

```
for(int i=0; i<cGlobals.mNames.length; i+=2)
{
    LinearLayout layout = new  LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    layout.setGravity( Gravity.CENTER );
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layout.setLayoutParams(llp);
    AddButton( layout, cGlobals.mNames[i], i);

    TextView t=new TextView(this);
    t.setText("    ");
    layout.addView(t);

    if (i+1<cGlobals.mNames.length)
         AddButton( layout, cGlobals.mNames[i+1], i+1);

    Container.addView(layout);
}
```

code that creats the buttons added to the linar layout

```
void AddButton( LinearLayout layout,  String name, int i)
{    

    favBut[i]=new ImageView(this);
    if ( cGlobals.conFav.contains( name )  )
        favBut[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.heartselected2);
    else
        favBut[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.heartunselected2);

     favBut[i].setId(defStartFavId+i);
     favBut[i].setOnClickListener(this);

     layout.addView(favBut[i]);

     int w=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
     w-=200; // hearts
     w=w/2;


     Button but1=new Button(this);
     but1.setText( name);
     but1.setWidth(w);
     layout.addView(but1);

     but1.setOnClickListener(this);
     but1.setId(defStartButId+i);       

}
```

XML file for layout

```
 <LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center" 
android:orientation="horizontal" > 

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/butVol"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24px"
        android:text="Volume"   
        android:textColor="#ff0000ff"
        android:layout_gravity="center" 
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/butRington"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24px"
        android:text="Rington"  
        android:textColor="#ff0000ff"
        android:layout_gravity="center" 
    />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to specify layout parameters like this...

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
layout.addView(favBut[i], layoutParams);
```

and/or

```
Container.addView(layout, layoutParams);
```

and maybe change MATCH_PARENT to WRAP_CONTENT depdning on the results you are after.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html

Comment: Hi,I'm confuse, the horizontal layout is set to WRAP_CONTENT right now

Comment: @Tedpottel just try the above first, never mind my comment about wrap_content.  If it doesn't work then change the top line defining the layout parms to wrap_content, wrap_content.